# Decode Opera cache content

Tags: c#, caching, opera, browser-cache

I found in http://www.nirsoft.net several browsers' cache viewers. My question relates to only Opera that I wish to learn what apis, functions or methods were used to decode tmp content (opera cache files) into URLs ? I am thankful if you could help, please explain something..

Comment: Opera documents its file formats here: http://www.opera.com/docs/operafiles/#opfileform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work pretty nicely for me:

```
strings .opera/cache/dcache4.url | egrep -o '(https?|ftp)://.*$'
```

Returns 1944 urls on separate lines for me. If you look at the output of `strings` you'll find that it looks pretty easy to find out *which* `.tmp` file under `.opera/cache` is related to *which* url too.

--

- `strings` is a UNIX utility in `binutils`; the source code is pretty simple and can be found [here](http://sourceware.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/src/binutils/strings.c?rev=1.48&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup&cvsroot=src) among other places
- `egrep` just matches a regular expression against the strings; `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match` would do exactly the sam from C#

Answer (score 2):

Opera [publicly documents](http://www.opera.com/docs/operafiles/) the file format used by the cache file, which should help. (If it doesn't, say so (and why!), and I can push to get the documentation improved!)